# Inserting HTML and Scripts onto page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div data-video="gPXSs-6qRFc"
 data-autoplay="1"
 data-loop="1"
 id="youtube-audio">
</div>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
```

If I stick this in the HTML, the div becomes populated with a play button, and the corresponding Youtube video (audio) will start to play. However, if I use Javascript to stick it on the page some time after the page has loaded, the div fails to become populated (I assume this is because the `script`s we've added don't run).

Using Javascript (triggered by a user action), how can I put this content onto the page and make these scripts run?

Comment: not sure if misunderstand the question, but the "Detecting when the script has been executed" section in https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/1383168 might help

Comment: When injecting the div using javascript, are you also injecting the script tags? Or are they already included in the page?

Comment: I'm injecting the whole thing. I wanted to keep it all contained within my JS file until it was ready to go on the page and run.

Comment: Could you try leaving in the html the youtube script only, after injecting the div and the other script